# Default route only for [POST] - Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

When specifying a return URL for PayPal on my web site, I get the following error:

> No route matches [POST] "/"

I would like to specify a default route for the `POST` method.

How can I make that the default `'root'` route accepts also `POST` requests?
Can I specify separate `'root'` routes for `POST` and `GET` requests?

My route currently looks like this:

```
root GET / refinery/pages#home
```

Incidentally I'm using Refinery CMS

Comment: My routes.rb file looks like this: mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/' I would prefer to keep this as a generic question and not paste here the 124 lines that Refinery mounts on / Is it possible in a generic way to match root POST requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally what worked for me was a `match` plus a `redirect`:

```
match "/" => redirect("/"), :via => :post
```

This converted a `POST` request to `/` into a `GET` request. Otherwise, the request goes to the correct route but it continues to be a `POST` request and this makes that my session is not loaded.  I'm still not sure why a `POST` request to `/` doesn't load the original session I had before going to PayPal and coming back.

Answer (score 1):

I think `root` *is* a `GET` request, it "wants" to specify how the application should answer if it was called by the domain name only (or the mount-path of the engine for that matter).

You might try to use a

```
match "/", :via => :post ...
```

but if you permit the return-question: why do you insist that PayPal should post to your root-URL? You should be able to specify an arbitrary URL there, just define a

```
match "postback" => "...", :via => :post
```

and be all fine with it.

Btw: sanny Sin asked you to post the output of the `rake routes` command, input it on your command line (and omit the refinery routes most probably :-)

Comment: This worked: match "/" => "refinery/pages#home", :via => :post